# List the next couple occuring birthdays in excel

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula

Given the following data

```
A         B
Steven    01/05/1958
Mike      05/12/1923
Bob       05/11/2001
Richard   10/22/1985
Maverick  12/25/1991
Ed        01/07/1954
```

I'd like to get a list in, let's just say the column D, containing the next couple birthdays that will occur.

So if today was 05/05/2016, I'd like to see

```
D       E
Bob     05/11/2001
Mike    05/12/1923
```

My current approach (yet not working properly) is to create another column and have the days until the birthday calculated there, using this formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR(B2)+DATEDIF(B2+1;TODAY();"y")+1;MONTH(B2);DAY(B2))-TODAY()
```

Then I list the birthdays that come up in the next 5 days using:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$2:$C$5,SMALL(IF($A$2:$C$5<5,ROW($A$2:$A$5)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$2:$C$5,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$5<5,ROW($A$2:$A$5)),ROW(1:1)),2))
```

I'd rather have **the next 5 upcoming birthdays**, no matter how far away from today they are.

Any Ideas how to achieve this without using makros?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are your dates in column B stored as a number or as a string?

Comment: you birthdate of 1785 will require a bit of work since excel date handling starts usually around the 1900 mark depending on your setup

Comment: What is A2?  your IF statement has is in the logical portion of the IF statement.  But then you go on to treat it as a date.

Comment: accoding to the [MS article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) you could reduce your first formula to `=DATEDIF(A2,today(),"YD")  That should give you the number of days since the birsthday.  So if you use LARGE instead of SMALL, you should get the birthday sorted by the next upcoming ones.

Comment: @ForwardEd I'm sorry, it was not supposed to be in the 18th century :D They're all living persons, so probably none of the birthdays is before 1900. 
Dates are stored as numbers.
Bot sure what you mean with "What is A2". Are you talking about the first or the second formula?
I can confirm that the shorter version works, though giving the remaining days requires knowing the total amount of days in the year, which is different every 4 years... approximately 4 years :D

Comment: yeah I caught that leap year issue with DATEDIF when I did a test.  wound up getting Mike and BOB with the same number of days away despite having different dates.   The A2 question for your first formula.  It starts out with IF(A2,...,"").  So when A2 is false you get a blank, and when A2 is true you do your formula.  And your formula makes me think the contents of A2 is a date.

Comment: I added two more entries to your example data as the way it was, you would just return the whole list!

Comment: looks like you have an answer.  You first formula in not making sense to me based on your example data for another reason.  You are using year(A2) in it.  but your example data, A2 is Mike.

Comment: What do you plan on doing if you have more than 5 people with the same birthday? or are you planning on just indicating that there is just a birthday coming up but not who it applies to?

Comment: I never knew you could do an IF(cell, true, false) to evaluate if cell was empty.  I always used something along the lines of IF(ISBLANK(cell)... or IF(CELL=""...

Comment: @ForwardEd yeah, you got me there, it was a clear copy paste mistake i did when I took it out of my excel sheet. This way it should make more sense. Ignored the IF(...) as it does not contribute to the problem

Comment: so how do you plan on treating people born on the 29th of February?  Excel will normally treat the 29th of February as march 1st for non leap years.  Do you plan an letting people born on the 29th only have a birthday every 4 years?

Comment: Fortunately my database is small enough to not have anybody at that date atm. All I'm trying to achieve is to have a fast way of looking up who I have to send an email in the next couple days. As I'm colorblind, highlighting the cells with a date close to now (which is recommended on the internet for such purposes) is not cool... If you want to extend this to take care of leap-year- birthdays... go ahead ;)

Answer (score 1):

To get the birthday difference from today in days :

```
=(DATEDIF($D$1,DATE(IF((DATE(YEAR($D$1),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))>$D$1),YEAR($D$1),YEAR($D$1)+1),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2)),"D"))+0
```

The first BD from current date :

```
=VLOOKUP(SMALL(A2:A8,1)+0,A2:B8,2,FALSE)
```

Please see the img for more details :[image: excel_BD]

Comment: the nice touch on this would be tor turn around and display the names beside the birthday.  You could do that with the Index(namelist, match(nextbirthday,birthdatelist,0).  the added twist on that would be different people born on the same day.

Comment: Just thinking about this, you are not listing their birthDATE, but their birthDAY.  So the year for every birthday has to either be either the current year or next year.

Comment: I'm using the current and next year to get the DateDif in days. But the birthDATE can any years.

The SMALL function "can handle" ppl born on the same day, but the VLOOKUP will pick the first x. So if the 4th 5th and 6th BD is the same date it will drop 1.

Comment: Doesn't your first formula and my first formula do the same? Or am I missing a trick yours can do and my can't

Answer (score 0):

OK slightly different approach

Instead of counting days in a helper column, change the date in a helper column.  Then sort that helper column for only the first 5 entries.  This will show upcoming birthDAYS instead of birthDATES.

So assuming Names in column A, Dates in Column B, Column C is created with:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+IF(TODAY()>DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2)),1,0),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))
```

Now I was assuming no header rows and A1 was the first entry so to display the next 5 entries in column D I used:

```
=IF(ROW()<=5,SMALL($C$1:$C$6,ROW()),"")
```

Now this will not pull names but just the upcoming birthDAYS not birthDATES.  The year being the difference between the two.

If you want to pull the names as well you can use the following:

```
=IF(D2<>"",INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MATCH(D2,$C$1:$C$6,0)),"")
```

Right now it will not return names of multiple people with the same date but there are ways around that.  If you need that too let us know.

```
(A)         (B)         (C)         (D)         (E)
Steven      58/01/05    17/01/05    16/05/11    Bob
Mike        23/05/12    16/05/12    16/05/12    Mike
Bob         01/05/11    16/05/11    16/10/22    Richard
Richard     85/10/22    16/10/22    16/12/25    Maverick
Maverick    91/12/25    16/12/25    17/01/05    Steven
Ed          54/01/07    17/01/07
```

### UPDATE

In order to deal with duplicate birthdays... try the following:

```
=IF(E5<>"",INDEX($A$1:$A$6,MATCH(E5,$C$1:$C$6,0)+COUNTIF($E$1:E5,E5)-1),"")
```

That was the entry for row 5.  I tested it with the same birthdate, but I forgot to check for same birthday (different years).

### UPDATE 2

NEW TABLE
The table below matches to formula from the last update

```
(A)         (B)         (C)         (D)   (E)       (F)         (G)
Steven      58/01/05    17/01/05    59    16/05/11  Bob         15
Mike        23/05/12    16/05/12    93    16/05/12  Mike        93
Bob         01/05/11    16/05/11    15    16/10/22  Richard     31
Richard     85/10/22    16/10/22    31    16/12/25  Maverick    25
Maverick    91/12/25    16/12/25    25    16/12/25  Ed          21
Ed          95/12/25    16/12/25    21
```

I inserted a column in D which shifted things right.  The following was placed in D1.

```
=year(C1)-Year(B1)
```

In column G I had it lookup the age

```
=IF(E1<>"",INDEX($D$1:$D$6,MATCH(E1,$C$1:$C$6,0)+COUNTIF($E$1:E1,E1)-1),"")
```

Comment: This should only bugger you up if you needed the day count for something else.

Comment: Did you try it with two birthdays on the same date? Cuz thats not working for the name pulling for me. 
This looks like a nice approach though, still have to figure out which one works better...

Comment: both work, and if you are using a small database it will not really matter.  I would look at whichever one has the simpler formulas, fewer helper columns, and fewer functions calls like index, match, vlookup.  I'll have to look up how to pull back duplicate entries but it should definitely be possible.  One questions I meant to ask, but stopped because I thought I may have been nit picking possible break points too much is what do you want to do if you have more than 5 people with birthdays on the same date?

Comment: I was thinking about how you could deal with multiple birthdays exceeding 5,  You could do another helper column, and do a =countif() to count duplicates.  You take the maximum from that column or 5 and you set that nth row criteria cut off when you are setting displaying  upcoming birthdays.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use the `Advanced Filter`.  And you could automate it using VBA.

For the Criteria:

```
A2:  =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))>=TODAY()
B2:  =(TODAY()+$C$2)>=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(B6),DAY(B6))
```

Range is the number of days after today to show birthdays.

[image]

Comment: Since the OP had asked how to achieve this without macro, I had assumed this ruled out VBA.  But from a VBA approach, yes nice option for automation.